# Comparing global sales of video game publishers

Tags: python, data-visualization

I am trying to create a function which can visualize(compare) two items of 'Platform', 'Genre' and 'Publisher' according to the 'Global_Sales' in different 'Year'.

The DataFarame looks like:
[image]

Code:

```
def compare_two(by, first, second):
    """
      by: Genre or Platform or Publisher
      first: first item from 'by'
      second: second item from 'by'
    """
    try:
      f_plat = df[df[by] == first]
      s_plat = df[df[by] == second]

      f_plat = f_plat.sort_values('Year', ascending=True)
      f_grouped = f_plat.groupby('Year')['Global_Sales'].sum()
      f_frame = f_grouped.to_frame(str(first) + '_Global_Sales')

      s_plat = s_plat.sort_values('Year', ascending=True)
      s_grouped = s_plat.groupby('Year')['Global_Sales'].sum()
      s_frame = s_grouped.to_frame(str(second) + '_Global_Sales')

      con_df = pd.concat([f_frame, s_frame], axis=1)
      con_df.reset_index(drop = False , inplace = True)
      con_df = con_df.fillna(0)
      con_df.sort_values(by='Year')

      fig_dims = (15, 7)
      ax = con_df.plot(x='Year', y= str(first) + '_Global_Sales', legend=False,
            figsize=fig_dims, kind='line')
      con_df.plot(x="Year", y= str(second) + '_Global_Sales', ax=ax, legend=False, color="r", 
           kind='line')
      ax.figure.legend()
      plt.show()
    except:
       print(">>>>>>>>Can't execute! check the function call<<<<<<<<<<<<<")

compare_two('Publisher', 'Nitendo', 'Activision')
```

The output looks like:
[image]

Is any way to optimize the above code?

Thank you for your valuable time !!

Comment: Can you please include a minimal dataset, so we can run your code? =)

Comment: And as a text block, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't need to sort at all, much less doing it twice over with the same criteria
- Why only accept two by-values, when you could accept an arbitrary number in a set?
- Your group-by criteria should be over both the year and your by-column
- No need to concat, reset any indices, fillna, etc.
- seaborn makes this easy

### Suggested

The data are garbage, slightly modified from what you gave us.

```
from io import StringIO
from typing import Set

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


def compare_sales(df: DataFrame, by: str, to_compare: Set[str]) -> None:
    df = df[
        df[by].isin(to_compare)
    ].groupby(
        ['Year', by], as_index=False,
    )['Global_Sales'].sum()
    sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Year', y='Global_Sales', hue=by)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inline_csv = (
        '''Rank,Name,Platform,Year,Genre,Publisher,NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales
        1,Wii Sports,Wii,2006.0,Sports,DEFINITELYNOTNintendo,41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74
        2,Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985.0,Platform,Nintendo,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24
        3,Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008.0,Racing,Nintendo,15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.82
        4,Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009.0,Sports,Nintendo,15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33.00                 
        5,Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996.0,Role-Playing,Nintendo,11.27,8.89,10.22,1.00,31.37                                        
        6,Tetris,GB,1989.0,Puzzle,Nintendo,23.20,2.26,4.22,0.58,30.26                        
        7,New Super Mario Bros.,DS,2006.0,Platform,Nintendo,11.38,9.23,6.50,2.90,30.01                                                                                                          
        8,Wii Play,Wii,2006.0,Misc,Nintendo,14.03,9.20,2.93,2.85,29.02                                                                                      
        9,New Super Mario Bros. Wii,Wii,2009.0,Platform,Nintendo,14.59,7.06,4.70,2.26,28.62                                                                                         
        10,Duck Hunt,NES,1984.0,Shooter,Activision,26.93,0.63,0.28,0.47,28.31
        11,Nintendogs,DS,2005.0,Simulation,Activision,9.07,11.00,1.93,2.75,24.76
        12,Mario Kart DS,DS,2005.0,Racing,Activision,9.81,7.57,4.13,1.92,23.42
        '''
    )

    with StringIO(inline_csv) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)

    compare_sales(df, 'Publisher', {'Nintendo', 'Activision'})
```

[image: Example seaborn]

Comment: Thank you Renderian ! and sorry for the garbage data !